# How to generate model from MS SQL with fields and NOT properties. Using EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unity-game-engine, auto-generate, ef-power-tools

I'm using (EF Core power tools -> Reverse enginiring) to generate classes from MS SQL database.

It generates **properties** like:

```
public string Password { get; set; }
public string PositionId { get; set; }
```

But I need it to be **fields** like:

```
public string Password;
public string PositionId;
```

Is there a way to do so? Will it affect the data manipulating ways?

I need it to be fields becouse Unity's JSONUtility only work with fields and not properties. And since my model should be the same at the server and at the client.

Comment: Simple: Do not use `JsonUtility` ... use `Newtonsoft Json.NET` instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yeah. I looked at the problem in the wrong angle.

Using **Newtonsoft.Json** instead of the **Unity's JsonUtility** solve the problem.